# How to display HeaderedItemsControl's Header?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, headereditemscontrol

I have the following code:

```
 <Window.Resources>      
       <DataTemplate x:Key="SectionTemplate" >                          
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />                  
       </DataTemplate>
 </Window.Resources>
 <Grid >        
   <Border>
       <HeaderedItemsControl Header="Top1"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=List1}" 
                             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SectionTemplate}"/>
    </Border>       
 </Grid>
```

```
public class MainWindow
{
   public List<Item> List1
   {
      get { return list1; }
      set { list1 = value; }
   }

   public MainWindow()
   {             
      list1.Add(new Item { Name = "abc" });
      list1.Add(new Item { Name = "xxx" });

      this.DataContext = this;      
      InitializeComponent();       
   }   
}

public class Item
{     
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

For some reason the `Items` are rendered, but without the header.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.headereditemscontrol.aspx) points out:

> A HeaderedItemsControl has a limited default style. To create a HeaderedItemsControl with a custom appearance, create a new [ControlTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate.aspx).

So when you create that template make sure to include some [`ContentPresenter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.aspx) which is bound to the `Header` (e.g. using [`ContentSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.contentsource.aspx))

e.g.

```
<HeaderedItemsControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type HeaderedItemsControl}">
        <Border>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" />
                <Separator Grid.Row="1" />
                <ItemsPresenter Grid.Row="2" />
            </Grid>
        </Border>                       
    </ControlTemplate>
</HeaderedItemsControl.Template>
```

(*All the default bindings (Margin, Background, etc.) are omitted.*)

Comment: Where does <HeaderedItemsControl.Template> go in the XAML?

Comment: @Doug: Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788723.aspx#property_element_syntax).

Comment: This is indeed a limited default style - in my opinion the default style should at least display the header in a very basic manner.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `DataTemplate` for the header, just as you did for the items (which is surely less intrusive than redoing the entire control template).

e.g.

```
<Window.Resources>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderTemplate">
  </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<HeaderedItemsControl Header="Top1"
                      HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=List1}"
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SectionTemplate}"
                      />
```

Instead of using e.g. "Top1" as here, you can bind to an object and then use binding relative to that object in the DataTemplate.

There is one gotcha with this approach, which is that the necessary approach to getting styles pulled in for non-control elements (notably `TextBlock`) is a little convoluted; also see [WPF Some styles not applied on DataTemplate controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476305/wpf-some-styles-not-applied-on-datatemplate-controls).  (You might also run into this with the ControlTemplate approach.)