# Style is being overridden when value uses Binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, styles

I have two styles set in my `UserControl.Resources`

> ```
>     <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
>         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="white" />
>     </Style>
>     <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
>         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="white" />
>     </Style>
> ```

So that in my `DataTemplate` (and note that I chopped the rest off) I will have white text applied without having to change the properties on each and every `Label` and `TextBlock` element.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="FileTransferItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="Transferring With: " />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=OtherUserName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

What happens though(and this caused me a long nightmare where I thought I was databinding improperly because I couldn't see any changes), is when the data is bound the foreground color defaults to black. My databound text was black on a black background, and I didn't even realize for the longest time.

The only way I can override this is manually setting the `Foreground="White"` on the `TextBlock`. The `Label` works fine for the color, because it's not databound.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: If you replace the binding by some text, you'll realize that the problem hasn't got anything to do with the binding.

Comment: Default style for TextBlock seems to be ignored in a DataTemplate. Found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13293627/1136211), although it's Silverlight, not WPF. See also [this page](http://www.11011.net/archives/000692.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not related to binding. It just seems that the lookup of an externally defined default style from inside a DataTemplate only works for elements that are derived from Control. Since TextBlock isn't derived from Control, your default style is not found.

[This page](http://www.11011.net/archives/000692.html) cites the following two statements given by Microsoft:

> This behavior is 'By Design' and this is why. Templates are viewed as
>   an encapsulation boundary. Elements produced by these templates fall
>   within this boundary. And lookup for a style with a matching
>   TargetType stops at this boundary. Hence the TextBlock in the repro
>   which is produced through a template does not pick up the Style in
>   question. Whereas the TextBlock defined outside the template does. 
>   One way to work around this problem is to give an explicit name to the
>   Style and reference the style by this name on the TextBlock within the
>   template.

and

> Templates are viewed as an encapsulation boundary when looking up an
>   implicit style for an element which is not a subtype of Control.

Comment: Well that certainly helps me understand that it's at least not my fault.