# How Style applies to child controls?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I expect the following `Style` to affect any `Border` that is child of the `Expander` object to which this `Style` is applied to have a 1-pixel thick gray border. Why doesn't it work?

```
<Style TargetType="Expander">
  <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Border>
          <Border.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
              <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
              <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
            </Style>
          </Border.Resources>
          <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />
        </Border>
      </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Element will check for implicit style through whole visual tree only if it inherits from `System.Windows.Controls.Control`. If it doesn't (like `TextBlock` or `Border`), and is placed in template, will check only in that template and `Application.Resources` skipping whole visual tree

Comment: @dkozl: grrrrrr... but thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476305/wpf-some-styles-not-applied-on-datatemplate-controls) answer